# Making Prettier understend TS "as" operator when it is working with eslint

Tags: typescript, eslint, prettier

I'am tring to use Prettier with ESLint for TS. But it's fails with an error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier, expected the token `)` (17:55)
```

On line with

```
const initialState = !process.env.IS_SERVER ? (window as any).__INITIAL_DATA__ : {};
```

This errror related with prettier.

I have installed all recomended plugins for ES to work with prettier and TS.
ES config here (.eslingrc.js):

```
module.exports = {
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser", // Specifies the ESLint parser
  extends: [
    "plugin:react/recommended", // Uses the recommended rules from @eslint-plugin-react
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended", // Uses the recommended rules from the @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint", // Uses eslint-config-prettier to disable ESLint rules from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin that would conflict with prettier
    "plugin:prettier/recommended" // Enables eslint-plugin-prettier and eslint-config-prettier. This will display prettier errors as ESLint errors. Make sure this is always the last configuration in the extends array.
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
    sourceType: "module", // Allows for the use of imports
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true // Allows for the parsing of JSX
    }
  },
  rules: {
    // Place to specify ESLint rules. Can be used to overwrite rules specified from the extended configs
    // e.g. "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: "detect" // Tells eslint-plugin-react to automatically detect the version of React to use
    }
  }
};
```

I use IDE WebStorem.
Operator extends for types fails with prittier too.

Why it is don't understand "as" operator?
Help me, please.

Comment: @AkashKava Not true, nowadays ESLint works with Typescript as well if setup with `@typescript-eslint/parser`

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a `.prettierrc` file then add `"parser": "typescript"` to the object.

```js
{
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "parser": "typescript"    <<----
}
```

If you're not using a `.prettierrc` file then @Steve Tomlin's answer should do the trick.

Comment: In VSCode, after making this change, I had to reload the window for the Prettier extension to use the new configuration.

Answer (score 1):

In .eslintrc add **parser** as "typescript".

```js
rules: {
  "prettier/prettier": ["error", {"singleQuote": true, "parser": "typescript", "endOfLine": "auto"}]
}
```

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score -2):

Check, **prettier** file config extension (.prettierrc.json)